# Check if a Sheet is Protected in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which deletes a value from a locked sheet. Whenever I run the code, Error message

> Delete method of Range class failed

is displayed. How do I prompt the user with a message such as `first unprotect the sheet`?

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
        Else
            rng.delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will Work:

[`Activesheet.ProtectContents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protectcontents) will tell you if a sheet is protected or not.

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then

        With Selection.Cells(1)
            Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
            Else
                rng.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        End With

    Else: MsgBox "Unprotect the Sheet First!"

    End If

End Sub
```